# RGB Image doesn't load correctly from ByteArray: opencv java (wrapped in scala)

Tags: java, scala, opencv

I have a camera streaming raw RGB data to the cloud.
I am picking up that data and processing it in Spark (using scala and OpenCV Java). 
I am having a problem loading correctly the RGB. This is the original image:

[image]

And this is what I am getting instead:

[image]

The code I am using for this is:

```
//mainCam is a byte array: val mainCam: Array[Byte]

val mainCam_mat = new Mat (360, 480, CvType.CV_8UC3)
mainCam_mat.put(0,0,mainCam)

//Destination is the path and file name e.g. /tmp/test/123.jpeg
Highgui.imwrite(destination, mainCam_mat)
```

Based on the input below I tried forcing the little endiann and using intbuffers this way:

```
//mainCam is a byte array: val mainCam: Array[Byte]
val bb = IntBuffer.allocate(mainCam.length/4)
bb.put(ByteBuffer.wrap(mainCam).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer()) 
mainCam_raw.put(0,0,bb.array.map(_.toByte))
//Destination is the path and file name e.g. /tmp/test/123.jpeg
Highgui.imwrite(destination, mainCam_mat)
```

The result is this:

[image]

Thanks Leonardo for suggesting that data was coming as 4 Channel RGBA. Updating the code to:

```
//mainCam is a byte array: val mainCam: Array[Byte]
val mainCam_mat = new Mat (360, 480, CvType.CV_8UC4)
mainCam_mat.put(0,0,mainCam)
//Destination is the path and file name e.g. /tmp/test/123.jpeg
Highgui.imwrite(destination, mainCam_mat)
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

There is still some grain on the image compared to the first visualization. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and also read [ask]. You haven't included enough detail for anyone to help you.  I'd check to make sure your java code isn't somehow "decoding" the bytes as characters, which would corrupt things, and also make sure the byte order is correct (little-endian vs big-endian).  Beyond that we'd have to see a lot more code.

Comment: Is your raw streaming image 360*480? It seems the original image is bigger.

Comment: @ Suhyeon Lee. Yes the original image is 360*480. The picture I posted is deceptive because I made a screencapture on the remote machine that is sending the data.

In the mean time I have tried what @ Jim Garrison suggested on little endian with this:

val bb = IntBuffer.allocate(mainCam.length/4) bb.put(ByteBuffer.wrap(mainCam).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer()) 
mainCam_raw.put(0,0,bb.array.map(_.toByte))

the result was better but not perfect. I will post it up

Comment: To me it seems you are receiving an image with 4 channels and reading it as if it was 3. Try using BGRA or RGBA format.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo!
The image came indeed as one when I mapped the byte Array to a mat of type CvType.CV_8UC4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your comments! They pointed me in the right direction.

In the end I went back to the source and found that the configuration was changed. I was getting 640*480 image with RGB channels.

This code works:

```
//mainCam is a byte array: val mainCam: Array[Byte]
val mainCam_mat = new Mat (480, 640, CvType.CV_8UC3)
mainCam_mat.put(0,0,mainCam)
//Destination is the path and file name e.g. /tmp/test/123.jpeg
Highgui.imwrite(destination, mainCam_mat)
```

The result:

[image]